# Thread scheduling issue with MFC and AfxBeginThread

Tags: multithreading, mfc, scheduling

I'm creating a worker thread in MFC with AfxBeginThread, but the thread is not getting scheduled. Here's the code:

```
CWinThread* worker = AfxBeginThread(initialUpdateWorkerThread, this);
DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
while(GetExitCodeThread(worker->m_hThread, &dwExitCode))
{
    if(dwExitCode != STILL_ACTIVE)
        break;
    ::Sleep(100);
}
```

When I run this, this loop just livelocks because initialUpdateWorkerThread is never called (I've put break points and message boxes at the top of it) so dwExitCode is always STILL_ACITVE. But if I put in a call to AfxMessageBox before the loop but after AfxBeginThread then the function is called. This makes me think that somehow I'm not calling the right function to get the thread scheduled, but a call to AfxMessageBox causes it to get scheduled.

How can I force the thread to be scheduled? I would think sleep would do that, but in this case it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Strange. You're using AfxBeginThread in the simplest way there is, so it should obviously just work. Is that the exact code you're running, or are you passing is some other arguments? Also, would be interesting to place a breakpoint right before the `while`, and see where the new thread is hanging.

Comment: I'm not buying.  However, your wait loop is completely borked, it assumes that SILL_EXECUTING is returned when it is busy.  Without checking that it even got started.  You have to use WaitForSingleObject(worker->m_hThread) to detect when it is done.  No need for the nasty wait loop either.

Comment: I've also tried using WaitForSingleObject and that did not work as well (it just hangs or times out if I set a time limit). How do I check to see if the thread got started? Also this is the exact code that I'm running; I copy-pasted it from my source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your worker thread is probably trying to send your main thread a message, but since you aren't processing messages on on the main thread, the worker thread simply waits. You can confirm this by simply breaking into the debugger to see what the worker thread is doing.

Comment: Yes you are exactly right. I was calling "((CMainFrame *)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd)->EnableWindow(FALSE);" At the very top of the worker function and I had been placing my breakpoints lower (there's a bunch of variable declaration at the top and I didn't notice this actual call in them). After I call "DoMsgTranslations()", which just iterates through all the messages and handles them, in the main thread, my worker thread now runs. Thank you for your help.